# How to access elements of a list in a class object?

Tags: python, pyscal

I'm new to python and trying to understand the basics using the [pyscal](https://pyscal.org/) module. I am trying to find the positions of each atom in each molecule at each snapshot (timepoint). From what I understand, `customkeys` in the following defines a list, whereas `sys` is a class object containing the different snapshots of my system, where each snapshot is a timepoint containing the positions of all atoms in all molecules.

I want to do something like iterate over the class object to obtain the positions of all of the atoms in each molecules at each timepoint. So I do the following:

```
sys = ml.to_system(customkeys=["mol"])

for mol in sys:
    each_molec = atom.pos
    print(each_molec)
    print(mol)
```

The first `print` statement outputs only the positions of the very last atom in the system, and the second print statement outputs something that I don't understand like:

`<pyscal.core.System object at 0x7f84eab9a900>`

Alternatively, I can access the molecule number for a particular atom in an particular snapshot by something like:

```
sys[1].atoms[1].custom["mol"]
```

**How, then, do I properly access the list in the class object and output the positions for each element (if that's the right word) of the list?**

Comment: Before we begin, DO NOT USE `sys` as a variable name.  `sys` is the name of a critical module in Python, and your use will hide the imported module.

Comment: You're using `atom.pos` in your loop, but your loop provides `mol`.  Where does `atom` come from?

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you. I had no idea about the `sys` module. Very good to know. I'm trying to find the atoms in each molecule. Like I said, I can access that for an individual atom by sys[1].atoms[1].custom["mol"]. I'll try adding to this in the comment to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `System` object contains a list of atoms.  So, I suspect you need something like:

```
system = ml.to_system(customkeys=["mol"])
for mol in system.atoms:
    print("Another molecule")
    for atom in mol:
        print(atom.pos)
```

However, the `pyscal` module is large and complicated. It's possible I misunderstood the documentation.

Comment: +1 Thanks. When I do that I get an error message: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'atoms'`. Also, I want to access the atom positions for each molecule, though, which is why in my original post I was iterating over each `mol`.

Comment: So, are you suggesting that, for a molecule, `atoms` is a list of LISTS of atoms?